# inserting a variable to a SQLite query

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, blackberry-10

I have a statement as follows.

```
 const QString createSQL = "CREATE TABLE customer (x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, y, z);" ;
```

I also have a variable

```
 QString name="name1";
```

I need to change the name of the table "customer" to name1. How do I insert the variable into the above sqlite query?

Comment: @laalto Um, so one can't do `SELECT * from ?`, for example?

Comment: @laalto Ugh, that's sad. (There should be a separate "name" type along with strings.)

Answer (score 1):

This is taken directly out of documentation.

```
// Execute query with positional binding using named placeholders
QVariantList contactValues;
contactValues << 1 << "Mike" << "Chepesky";
DataAccessReply reply = sc.executeAndWait(
    "insert into contact (id, firstname, lastname) values (:id, :firstname, :lastname)",
    contactValues);
```

and

```
// Execute query with positional binding using positional (?) placeholders
QVariantList contactValues;
contactValues << 1 << "Mike" << "Chepesky";
DataAccessReply reply = sc.executeAndWait(
    "insert into contact (id, firstname, lastname) values (?, ?, ?)",
    contactValues);
```

Look at [**documentation/source**](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__data__sqlconnection.html?f=sql)

Answer (score 0):

To rename a table, use `ALTER TABLE`:

```
"ALTER TABLE customer RENAME TO " + name
```

If you just needed to insert the table name to the query,

```
"CREATE TABLE " + name + "(x INTEGER ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change table names with bound variables but you can do this:

```
QString name = "tableName";
QString createSQL = QString("CREATE TABLE %1 (x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, y, z)").arg(name);
```

To answer H2CO3's comments you absolutely can to bound values:

```
QString queryStr = QString("SELECT * FROM TABLE %1 WHERE col = :selected").arg(name);
QSqlQuery query(qSqlDatabase);
query.prepare(queryStr);

query.bindValue(":selected", "Selected Value");
```